# Adhesive for cableways on internal brick

Tags: brick, cable-management

I have a television mounted (professionally) on an interior masonry brick wall, above my fireplace.  I also have cableways (cord-concealers) running on the surface of the brick wall, approximately five feet vertical (up) and two feet horizontal (over).

The cableway is rectangular, about 1.5" on the wider side, very similar to what is shown in the link below.

The amount of cabling inside the cableway is not excessive-- only two HDMI and a power cord-- but that cableway will not stay attached to the wall for love or money.  The adhesive on the cableway itself is not sufficient.  I've been applying ever-increasing amounts of mounting putty, to no avail.  The cableway stays stuck for a few hours, but rarely more than a day before the upper part starts peeling away.

What is a good adhesive (i.e., I am not looking to drill any more holes in my fireplace than are already there) to firmly bond plastic cableway to masonry brick in this situation?

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07F26FZS5/ref=sspa_dk_detail_4?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B07F26FZS5&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=f52e26da-1287-4616-824b-efc564ff75a4&pf_rd_r=51JBG5WSSEXF1J846XEH&pd_rd_wg=eBYbU&pf_rd_s=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_t=40701&pd_rd_w=qknDu&pf_rd_i=desktop-dp-sims&pd_rd_r=043417c4-d9b9-11e8-8a27-e7c97784a407](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07F26FZS5)

Comment: Why dont you drill? Whats the reason? Conduit is circular tube or rectangular? Pls post a photo.

Comment: Where exactly does the adhesive bond break down? Between the conduit and adhesive? Between the adhesive and the wall? Does any paint peal off the wall?

Comment: There is no paint, only exposed masonry bricks.  The back of the conduit is still very tacky-feeling and the brick is not, so the original adhesive remains on the conduit.  Usually, but not always, the mounting putty is staying on the conduit as well.

Comment: Is the power cord carrying AC mains or low voltage? Does the TV have an AC/DC power brick?  Is it up at the TV or on the floor?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica how does knowing this help recommend an adhesive for the conduit?